# How to ask python only for the new key:value pairs?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I am looking for is quite hard to explain, therefore I show you the code I already have and the output I am looking for. I tried various things found here in stackoverflow, but none of the solutions seemed applicable for my case as far as I could judge.

```
allGuests = {"Alice": {"apples": 5, "pretzels": 12}, "Bob": {"ham 
             sandwiches": 3, "apples": 2}, "Carol": {"cups": 3, "apple pies": 3}}
def totalBrought(guests, item): 
    numBrought = 0              
    for k, v in guests.items():                             
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0) 
    return numBrought
while True:
    print("Is there another Guest coming?")
    answer = input()  
    if (answer == "Yes") or (answer == "yes"):
        newdishesDic = {}
        print("Who is it? ")
        newguest = input() 
        while True:
            print("What does " + newguest + " bring to the picnic?")
            newdish = input()
            print("How much of it?")
            newquantity = input()
            newdishesDic[newdish] = int(newquantity)
            allGuests[newguest] = newdishesDic
            print("Anything else?")
            answer2 = input()
            if (answer2 == "") or (answer2 == "no") or (answer2 == "No"):
                break
            elif (answer2 == "Yes") or (answer2 == "yes"):
                continue
    elif (answer == "") or (answer == "no") or (answer == "No"):
        break
print(" - Apples: " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "apples")))
print(" - Pretzels: " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, "pretzels")))
....
```

And so forth. Outcome as follows:

```
- Apples: 7
- Pretzels: 12
- Cups: 3
...
```

As you can see, I add new Guests, dishes and quantities, and these are added to the existing allGuests dictionary. 
But how can I do the exact same "counting" as shown in the outcome with the new dishes without knowing them upfront?
I tried various approaches but in the "best case" I got the last added key value pairs since the variables are overwritten each iteration (does that make sense??)

I read about dict comprehension as a solution, but frankly speaking I did not really understand how to use it here. I tried to add the new inputs not only to the dictionary but to a new List as well, but then there won´t be any key-value pairs anymore so that didn´t work out. 
Anyone who can follow my vague and most likely confusing request?

Comment: "_But how can I do the exact same "counting" as shown in the outcome with the new dishes without knowing them upfront?_" Meaning? What are these new dishes?

Comment: since you know it's confusing, why not boil it down to a [mcve]. We'd like to help you but your question makes my head dizzy.

Comment: I am not sure what is the thing that you need. Are you familiar with `.items()`? Here it would be `for k,v in allGuests.items(): for k2,v2 in v.items():` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the guests and add their dishes into a set to get a complete set of all the dishes. Then just print the count of each dish.

```
allGuests = {"Alice": {"apples": 5, "pretzels": 12}, "Bob": {"ham sandwiches": 3, "apples": 2}, "Carol": {"cups": 3, "apple pies": 3}}
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
    return numBrought
while True:
    print("Is there another Guest coming?")
    answer = input()
    if (answer == "Yes") or (answer == "yes"):
        newdishesDic = {}
        print("Who is it? ")
        newguest = input()
        while True:
            print("What does " + newguest + " bring to the picnic?")
            newdish = input()
            print("How much of it?")
            newquantity = input()
            newdishesDic[newdish] = int(newquantity)
            allGuests[newguest] = newdishesDic
            print("Anything else?")
            answer2 = input()
            if (answer2 == "") or (answer2 == "no") or (answer2 == "No"):
                break
            elif (answer2 == "Yes") or (answer2 == "yes"):
                continue
    elif (answer == "") or (answer == "no") or (answer == "No"):
        break

all_dishes = set()
for guest, dishes in allGuests.items():
    all_dishes.update(dishes.keys())

for dish in all_dishes:
    print(" - " + dish +": " + str(totalBrought(allGuests, dish)))
```

Comment: Thanks!! That actually solved my "problem". I just tested it and it does exactly what I was looking for. Dont really understand yet how it actually works but that´s my job now I guess to figure that out and learn from it!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You want to generate a new dictionary, where you sum up all dishes of all guests.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sum_up_all_dishes(all_guests):
    dishes = defaultdict(int)
    for dish in all_guests.values():
        for name, amount in dish:
            dishes[name] += amount
    return dishes

all_guests = {
    "Alice": {"apples": 5, "pretzels": 12}, 
    "Bob": {"ham sandwiches": 3, "apples": 2},
    "Carol": {"cups": 3, "apple pies": 3}
}

while True:
    print("Is there another Guest coming?")
    answer = input()  
    if answer.lower() == "yes":
        newdishesDic = {}
        print("Who is it? ")
        newguest = input() 
        while True:
            print("What does {} bring to the picnic?".format(newguest))
            newdish = input()
            print("How much of it?")
            newquantity = input()
            newdishesDic[newdish] = int(newquantity)
            print("Anything else?")
            answer2 = input()
            if answer2.lower() in ("", "no"):
                break
        all_guests[newguest] = newdishesDic
    else:
        break
all_dishes = sum_up_all_dishes(all_guests)
for name, amount in dishes.items():
    print(" - {}: {}".format(name, amount))
```